Why do Electric Aircraft Seem to Eschew Photovoltaics?
I work in climate policy so I'm always excited for things that could help me feel less guilty about being into aviation such as biojet and the progress being made in electric propulsion.
To date, however, all of the examples of electric aircraft that I've seen lack photovoltaic equipment (i.e. solar panels). Given the concerns with electric propulsion seem to stem from a lack of energy/power density in current generation battery technology, this feels like a glaring omission.  Any amount of PV (sunk into the top of the wings, for example) would produce positive power and mitigate consumption of stored energy in batteries - even on cloudy days.
It's obvious that the systems are nowhere near sufficient to power flight, but given how on-the-margin electric propulsion operates it feels like low hanging fruit from an electrical power perspective.  You'd gain the operational benefits of refueling anywhere you could park it in the sun for long enough (to be fair, that'd likely take a LONG time).
I assume there's technical reasons to eschew the equipment, but I'm curious what the constraining factor(s) are, specifically.
The candidates I can think of up front are weight (silicon wafer isn't that heavy, plenty of PV can be made extremely lightweight and you need the wing to be rigid already so balance of structure isn't adding much, if anything), volume (silicon wafer is, pardon me, 'wafer thin'), technical complexity (this is an experimental aircraft we're talking about, remember) or cost (see previous) - all of which seem readily dismissed.
EDIT: I'm not asking about PV as primary power, I'm asking why engineers are leaving 'money on the table' as it were, by not including PV in battery-primary designs.
What am I missing?

Solar panel flowchart: https://xkcd.com/1924/

For clarity, by "electric aircraft" did you mean drones, or normal-size novelty experimental aircraft??

Whatever you put in the top of the wings must not interfere with the air flow that allows the wing to provide lift.

@Fattie The latter.

@David K - Yes, I'm talking about sinking the PV into the top surface of the airfoil as an integrated part of the wing's design, not crudely strapping something down with duct tape.

@WilliamWalkerIII I'm afraid that it clearly seems to be wildly outside the bounds. But one thing that comes to mind. There was a BM? Mercedes? model car where, ok so for on really hot days, obviously cars have fantastic air coinditioners when running. For sunny climes, you park for 20 minutes while buying your latter (at the mall I guess!) and of course the interior of the car is holy heck hot. Cracking the windows helps but is illegal/etc insecure in some places. Companies tried small exhaust fans ie run by the normal car battery but its not a reliable idea to use that battery. So, there wer

e 1 or 2 models which had (naturally as a paid optional extra :) ) basically the sunroof or some relaticvely large area oin the roof, was a solar panel, that drove some sort of "for when you are parked" cooling system for the car (it was probably just exchaust circulation fans, but maybe some sort of cooling, IDK.   Perhaps this kind of "incidental" use of panels could be relavent to what you're thinking.  PS if I'm not mistaken in a comment below, you mention that you were not aware! there are literally experimental extreme planes which fly using entirely solar power, this perhaps causes

some confusion on this QA.  Cheers!  I love solar power for the rare applicaton where it's useful, but it's incredibly "weak" you know?  :O

@Fattie When you're full electric those issues end up blurring together due to oversimplification.  Given the discussion thusfar it's looking like the answer is going to be some combination of 'every gram matters' and 'complexity raises cost and the add-on benefit doesn't justify that yet.'

@WilliamWalkerIII absolutely, I was talking about PETROL POWERED cars (those models were from way before the Tesla era). Your question is about PETROL POWERED planes, using, solar for "incidental" issues.  So i thought it was an interesting example.  (BTW planes will ONLY ever be "petrol powered", nothing else has the fuel density. The only possibility is nuclear power (fusion, fission, whatever) but it's very very unlikely that will ever be possible, as a light enough reactor, to beat petrol for energy density, is a sci-fi idea, made of unobtanium.

@Fattie I am not talking about petrol powered planes. I'm talking about fully electric aircraft such as a Archer Midnight, or Pipstrel Velis Electro.

@WilliamWalkerIII  'every gram matters' and 'complexity raises cost and the add-on benefit doesn't justify that yet.' i feel you're fully missing the far more obvious third option there.  the stunning, mindboggling, just UTTERLY INSANE amount of power that an airliner (big plane) produces just utterly, utterly dwarfs both (a) the "incidental" needs you discuss and indeed (b) what could be created by solar panels.  I'm not sure if you're aware, the big engines on big aircraft have (to summarize) stuck on them "merely" as an incidental matter pretty big electric generators which provide the enor

mous amount of electric power used by a big plane in flight, the enormous number of microwave ovens, 400 large TV sets, headlights, etc etc.  Anyway.

@WilliamWalkerIII "Archer Midnight, or Pipstrel Velis Electro" lol OK I've finally got you.  those are novelties that don't matter, but again (not saying anything novel)  it is "option three", the amount of "bonus power" you're talking about is simply irrelevant compared to the ginormous battery.  I'm afraid it's not your option 1 or 2, it's 3

@Fattie You seem to have a very negative view of innovation. If everyone in history felt that way, the only vehicles we would have would still be sandals. Energy densities are continually increasing and new motors are consuming less power. There are already commercial electric planes nearing production, so why dismiss a minor improvement.

@Suncat2000 I'm sorry to disagree! Solar panels are useless and, indeed, anti-innovation.  If you frame the viewpoint "solar panels are useless" as "anti-innovation" that's  ingenious debate wordplay, I'm afraid.

@Fattie "solar panels are useless" answers this question, and I don't see anything so strong said in the existing answers.  Perhaps add your own?

Standalone recharge anywhere... As said, the wing surface is too small, the aircraft will likely get grounded several days... Why not just put an array of solar panels finely calibrated for efficiency at many airfields ? Charge would complete fast, and work for a broad variety of aircraft size, ground vehicles and equipments ? The ground array would be easier to maintain and upgrade.
Wings aren't rigid ! Common misconception is "it has internal structure, therefore, it will remain straight..." Actually, over a couple meters, a wing bends. At microscopic level, it slowly deteriorates over time (wrincles/cracks). A layer of solar panels will rub the wing surface at contact level, especially along the edges and at the corners (is it glued or what ?). That's a technical issue, how often it has to get fixed to keep that upperwing clean (ie no aerodynamical disturbance) ?
Weather ! I know solar panels can be reinforced to withstand hail. In aviation, this translates to weight and extra costs. That's usually a big NO.
Efficiency. Solar panels lose efficiency with dust and scratches (we ignore the other causes to focus on those). Snow, dust, rain, hail... Even if it's just for supplement purposes, it has to be maintained well to have a meaning : how much hassle to care for ? What to do before each flight, what to do between flights ? What could go wrong if not properly handled ? Practically, the amount of care is much concerning than adding another battery, as mentionned.
Maintainance : One way to gain or lose money in the aviation industry is how much of a cost is maintaining engines and systems. Who's (company/subcontractors) in charge of ensuring maintainance of those solar panels ? If it's a small company only present in a few states in the US... You either need a company that can handle problems whatever the country, or a company that can qualify personnel, or a company that uses OEM components any developped country can produce (and not charge too much for patents...) - likely a combination of those.
Please rest assured I'm not here to discourage all efforts in building environmental friendly systems, components and behavior, but for practically everything, the purpose must have a meaning. An aircraft is meant to move people or goods over terrain or faster than any other way. To be efficient, weight has to get "donated" to payload as much as possible instead of structure, equipment and systems (unless safety is a concern), and the vehicle has to be as less of a hassle as possible to operate (unless safety is a concern). Your question ask for the "why not" rather than the "how to", therefore, we focus on the purpose, not the technical issues that can be solved in a way or another.
Experimental aircraft are nice, but sometimes, they fail to remember what was the purpose... You can build a self sustained fully electric aircraft, but if you can't put people and cargo inside, and/or it requires special care (qualified people, frequent checks, logistics/equipements, spare parts manufacturing...) on a daily basis which translate to utterly expensive costs the end user (you and me) has to pay...
On a related yet distant topic, it's very similar to "flying cars" : the purpose is to safely transport people over cities... quite a major safety concern : how would you ensure the everyday lambda anyone is qualified enough to actually fly that thing ? That's the answer why over 2 centuries of dream, yet, the drones-like advertised vehicles are still a long way before taking off from our backyard. The purpose, it being safety and/or "economically viable", should be at the center of the design process, from the start, not a concern one solve later. For an aircraft, you freeze payload and range first (for example), then you solve every major safety issue (means a LOT of dead weight), then you solve all other problems and assert if adding solar panels is a bonus or a malus. Not the other way around.

It depends on the specific use case, but in general, it's not worth it given the alternatives. The power delivered by solar panels is too low to have a meaningful impact.
Solar irrandiance is about 1361 W/m2 (best case, at the "top of atmosphere" irradiance. The surface irradiance is roughly 1000 W/m2 due to particles etc, thanks for the comment, Mark). If we assume about 10% efficiency for thin-film cells, that leaves about 136 W/m2 or 0.136 kW/m2.
So for the Pipistrel Velis Electro, with a wing surface of 9.51 m2 -even though some of that is flaps/ailerons that cannot as easily be used for solar cells-, that would give you 0.136 * 9.51  = 1.29 kW, at best (best case irradiance, full wing surface and ignoring cable/charging losses).
Compare this with the 35 kW delivered by the engines in cruise.
This is a bit over 3%  at the price of extra costs/weight/complexity. It's probably much less trouble to add 3% (~4.2kg) batteries.

I appreciate the maths here.  Assuming we don't plan the VFR reserve around the PV being available, the Pipistrel gets better than +5% endurance under those assumptions... but that's still just over 3 more minutes so it's illustrative of the de minimis nature of the impact for sure. What's interesting to me, though, is that it suggests a breakeven point at 34% efficient PV, technically outside the SQ Limit, but not by much.

@WilliamWalkerIII, how do you end up with the breakeven point at 34%? If 10% efficient cells deliver 3% of the cruise power, you would need 30x that to break even.

By breakeven, I assumed 20% increase in range would be worth the trouble (ten more minutes on the Pipstrel, plenty for at least one more lap around the pattern). So 3x the 10% gets you enough mitigation of battery drain that you can achieve that. The relationship isn't 1:1 because the constraint is "my batteries are at VFR reserve" so delaying that state is where the value comes from.

@WilliamWalkerIII add 90kg for the panels and we've probably lost the 3% range gain. Airplane efficience is very sensitive to weight. Pipistrels empty weight is only about 300kg...

@Jpe61 I'm dubious that the panels would weigh much at all - just the mass of the wafers and wiring, maybe a tiny increase in an inverter if one is needed (I suspect electric aircraft are fully DC). The reason PV panels have mass is because they're in frames, but if you're using the wing itself as a frame, I'd expect that to no longer be necessary - unless you're saying it definitely would be necessary to add further structure to wings to accomodate such, in which case that'd be a killer as you say.

@WilliamWalkerIII you are correct in that if they were specially manufactured for this purpose, then the weight would be much less. The wafers would need some protective films so they would not be insignificant in weight in any case, if we consider light aircraft such as Pipistrel.

@WilliamWalkerIII Paint is a significant weight on an airplane. Even assuming that the weight of the cells is all the extra weight added by this change (ha!), you would still see a significant increase.

That 1361 W/m2 is the "top of atmosphere" irradiance.  The surface irradiance is roughly 1000 W/m2, give or take things like particulates.

@Mark good point, added it. Kept the answer the same as a 'best case' scenario

@ROIMaison Other factors: The additional wiring and electronics (charge controllers) add weight to a plane (specifically the Velis) that has as much weight reduction as possible, including the removal of airbrakes that are useful on its sister petrol models for landing. The wiring of the panels has to be more complex to get the best out of the panels since they don't all point the same direction, ie more weight. Finally, the first Pipistrel electric (experimental) could regen from the windmilling prop on landing, to get certified they removed it from the Velis for in flight battery safety.

It's worth noting that there are commercial thin-film cells with efficiences exceeding 20%, and research points to 30-50%. On the other hand, latitude, time of the year, time of the day and weather mean that the actual received energy may be a lot less than 1000 W/m2 (especially in the case of the Pipistrel Velis Electro which is more likely to be below the clouds than above them), so overall the end result is probably going to be much worse than the 3% you got to.

@fectin That's a solid point, but paint also doesn't generate power/reduce battery mass. But if it's a game of grams, then it becomes very understandable that pv wafers will need to become far more power dense to earn their keep.

@Mark  - and that irradiance is a maximum, at mid-day, and at lattitudes near the equator - rather lower for Europe and the USA/Canada, I believe, and at dusk/daw, never mind at night.

As you state, "nowhere near sufficient to power flight". And that includes charging.
The Airbus Zephyr 8 has a 25 meter wingspan, and the top surface of the wing is ALL solar panels. It can keep itself aloft sort of indefinitely.
Change that flying to recharging, and scale down to realistic aircraft sizes, and you'd probably have to leave it outside for a week or two, just to recharge once.

I understand what happened here. Edited the question to clarify I'm not asking why PV isn't used as the primary/sole source of power, but rather supplemental to a battery-based scheme. Upvoting for the link to the Zephyr though, that's a new one for me.

Primary power or recharging, pretty much the same. Not enough surface area to provide enough power for the recharge in any rational timeframe.

That seems equivalent to saying "Sure, we could use less fuel, but this doesn't bring fuel use to zero, so it's not worth it." If I'm paying for the kWh to recharge on the field, why wouldn't paying less for that be a desirable trait?

@WilliamWalkerIII - Cost and complexity, for no meaningful gain.

@WilliamWalkerIII: Putting solar cells on the portion of a hangar roof facing the Sun would almost certainly cost less (in both initial and ongoing costs) than putting solar cells on a plane, but reap a lot more energy.  If airfields had solar cells installed everyplace they were practical, and still needed more energy, then it might be worth considering adding them to planes, but why add them to planes if an alternative woul be in every way better?

"Edited the question to clarify I'm not asking why PV isn't used as the primary/sole source of power, but rather supplemental to a battery-based scheme" because for ancillary minor power needs, it is out by 2? orders of magnitude.  the surface area of planes would need to be 100x larger, and, of course never fly other than cloudless high noon. :)


Any amount of PV (sunk into the top of the wings, for example) would produce positive power and mitigate consumption of stored energy in batteries - even on cloudy days.

That's fallacious. Sure, any amount of PV would increase gross power, but it's hardly guaranteed to increase net power. Adding PV means increasing the weight, which means higher power requirements. PV runs at about 20W/kg. A Boeing 737 takes about 100W/kg  to stay airborne. With more efficient aircraft and PV with better power/weight ratios, you can make this work, but it's far from trivial.

You'd gain the operational benefits of refueling anywhere you could park it in the sun for long enough (to be fair, that'd likely take a LONG time).

Why fly the PV around with the plane? Why not just put PV on the roof of the hangar? It's not like first-stage electric flight is going to be flying into the middle of nowhere. Departure and destination is going to both be to places with well-developed infrastructure.

The overwhelming majority of PV's mass is from frame and inverter equipment - a full electric plane, I assume, is either DC (no inverter needed) or already has an inverter to manage the power from the battery (again, no additional inverter needed).  The structural frame is also not needed here, because the wing/body already exist.
I challenge the claim that PV is as heavy as proposed, once we already have an all-electric airframe.  I'm happy to be proven wrong, and if you can do so with documentation this'll get accepted.

Solar panels were used to power AeroViroment unmanned aircraft developed under NASA's Environmental Research Aircraft and Sensor Technology (ERAST) program.
Four of them were developed from the middle of the '80s till the end of the last century, namely the Pathfinder, Pathfinder Plus,  Centurion and Helios.
Wikipedia has a good entry about them.

It's worth noting that there are solar-powered aircraft. The linked Wikipedia article lists 11 different models/ranges of aircraft, going back to 1974.
However, the limited amount of power one can get from solar cells compared to the power required for the aircraft, means that those aircraft are very specific, and:

Have a very large surface (Zephyr 8/S has a 25 m wingspan, Solar Impulse 71.9m)
Are extremely light-weight (25 kg for Zephyr 8/S, 2000 kg for solar Impulse)
Can only carry a very limited payload (5 kg for Zephyr 8/S, one single pilot in an unpressurised cockpit for Solar Impulse 2)
Usually fly very high to get maximal solar irradiance above the clouds
Usually fly very high to avoid turbulence, as they tend to be very fragile
Are usually quite slow (Solar Impulse's average speed was 76 km/h)
Usually fly pretty long missions so the proportion of flight in cruise is maximised
Many can't even take off by themselves and need to be launched with balloons or towed by other aircraft
Are experimental and are able to achieve their objectives only in very specific circumstances (locations, weather...)

Trying to scale that to anything useful to carry passengers on "normal" flights quickly breaks down completely: if you need a 71.9m wing span for an aircraft capable of carrying only a single pilot, imagine what you would need for even a few dozen people! And even more if you want that aircraft to be as sturdy and capable of flying in nearly any weather as a conventional airliner.
The end result is that, as demonstrated in other answers, for a "regular" aircraft, the amount of power you can get from solar cells on the existing wing span is just negligible, and also extremely variable (depends on latitude, time of the year, time of the day, weather...). Compared to the added cost and complexity, it's just not worth it.
In the very best of cases (aircraft in cruise at very high altitudes, far above the clouds, in daylight, with top of the line solar cells which only exist in research labs at this time), you could get probably 500 W/m2.
A 737 requires 7.2 MW just to keep altitude and speed. If we want to achieve 10% of that power (remember, in cruise, at high altitude) using these best-of-the-line-not-available-yet solar cells, we would need 1440 m2 of wing surface, about 10 times the actual wing surface.

As a supplement to ROIMason's answer, what if we used top-of-the-line solar panels?
The Airbus Zephyr 8/S is an unmanned vehicle weighing 65 kg with a payload of 5 kg and it can fly for over a month. We can use this as an example of what top-of-the-line solar panels can do on an aircraft.

...Solar cells are high-efficiency, lightweight, and flexible inverted metamorphic multi-junction epitaxial lift-off GaAs sheets manufactured by MicroLink Devices, with specific power exceeding 1,500 W/kg and areal powers greater than 350 W/m2.

Using the example of the Pipistrel Velis Electro, its wing area of 9.5 m^2 would deliver at best 3.3kW vs the 35kW cruising power, or 10% more power. For about 2kg (plus the extra hardware).
These are top-of-the-line "call us if you want pricing" components. We can assume they're not cheap.
The endurance of the Pipistrel Velis Electro is listed at 50 minutes. Is the cost to install and maintain top-of-the-line solar panels worth an extra 5 minutes of flight time? Probably not.

What was the monetary cost of those "top of the line" panels?
